# Angular 12 Routing Issues with IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-router

**Background**

We have an Angular 12 project that works across all major browsers and, in the most part, on IE 11. However, for some reason routing doesn't seem to be working anywhere within the app on IE 11. We are using the latest version of Angular (12.2.11) and have ensured that all packages are up to date. We are using Node 14.15.5.

**Problem**

If we simply use a link directly via href="/route", the relevant page is opened fine.

If we use...

```
this.router.navigate(['/route']);
```

...**then the destination Url is updated successfully in the IE 11 navigation bar, but the destination page does not load. It stays on the original page.** Weirdly, if we then press refresh, the destination page loads and the navigation history stack is correctly populated.

We don't think that it has anything to do with the various compatibility for IE 11 changes that are necessary, as we have set this up properly.

All routing works flawlessly in any modern web browser. We test in Chrome, Firefox, Safari amongst others before a release. We need to be compatible with IE 11 for some of our corporate customers.

**browerslist**

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-10
IE 11
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
"es2017",
"es2015",
"dom"
],
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'core-js/es/promise';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';

import 'classlist.js';

import 'web-animations-js';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

.. and npm install on classlist and web-animations

**Question**

What are we missing here? Slightly tearing my hair out here and I'm getting older so there's not much of that left! Has anyone else had this unexpected routing behaviour with IE 11 and know of a possible fix to this?

Comment: I made an example to test according to [this blog](https://appdividend.com/2020/07/10/understanding-angular-router-navigate-with-example/). `this.router.navigate()` works fine in IE 11. I can't reproduce your issue. Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue? Is there any error in console in IE when it doesn't work?

Comment: @YuZhou - thanks for trying to reproduce the issue. If we simply build a new Angular project, the issue does not occur in IE 11. It seems to be specifically within our project! We are currently removing sections of our app, one piece at a time to find out what is causing the issue. Real head scratcher!

Comment: Yes, it works well when I make a new Angular project. If there's any update, you can come back to post here.

Comment: So we have now spoken with the Angular team and after 3 days of investigation, we have found the culprit. We are using Segment to track actions within the app. This requires the insertion of a small piece of js code into the app and a window declaration in the app.module.ts. https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-angular - the generated polyfills contained a bug that was impacting routing within IE 11. Thank you @YuZhou for assisting, very kind. I guess the outcome for us is that if you get strange angular behaviour, start by looking at slightly awkward implementations within the project first

Comment: I'm glad that you have find the issue. You can post the solution for this issue and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.